# Why is the result of the following functor not opaque?

Tags: sml, functor, smlnj, ml, opaque-types

Consider the following SML program:

```
signature BinaryOp =
sig
    type domain
    val operation: (domain * domain) -> domain
end;

signature INTEGER =
sig
    val value: int
end;

functor ModularInt(K: INTEGER) :> BinaryOp =  (* I *)
struct
    type domain = int;
    fun operation (a,b) = (a+b) mod K.value;
end;

structure Z3 = ModularInt(struct val value=3 end);

structure Z3' :> BinaryOp = Z3;  (* II *)
```

It turns out that Z3 is *not* opaque, meaning that Z3.domain is compatible with integers
(i.e., `val x: Z3.domain = 0` works), whereas Z3' is opaque.

Why is opaque signature ascription (`:>`) doing its job on line II but not on line I?

Comment: Which SML are you using? I cannot reproduce that, `x` gets rejected as it should when I try.

Comment: Standard ML of New Jersey (64-bit) v110.99.3 @AndreasRossberg

Comment: Having tested with the same version of SML/NJ (albeit 32-bit) I can confirm the same behavior as the OP.

Comment: Interesting. This must be a bug in SML/NJ. You may want to report it.